# Firebreath plugin can't be loaded in IE9/IE10 if running IE as administrator

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, uac, firebreath

My firebreath plugin works well in IE9/IE10 when opening IE normally, until one day I unconsciously open IE as administrator explicitly, the plugin just can't load. I also tried Firebreath sample plugin that can't load in this case either.

I checked the event logged by IE compatibility test tool, and find IE just fail to instantiate my plugin. I guess this probably is related to some IE security settings that I've tried lots of modifications of IE options, but still won't work.

After many trials, I found a workaroud that if I disable the UAC (User Account Control) and restart computer, then the plugin can load successfully when running IE as administrator. 
On the other hand, I also tried other plugin (not created by Firebreath), e.g. Microsoft Windows Media Player control, that I have a simple page to embed it, and open it in IE10 as administrator, which can load and works well.

So, I don't know whether it is something wrong with my firebreath plugin or there are some options I need to figure out to change. Any suggestions are apprieciated.

Comment: Run Process Monitor and watch to see which registry references or file accesses fail in the Admin scenario but not in the User scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is most likely because firebreath installs by default per-user, which means when you run it as administrator it isn't installed for the administrator user.

There is a setting in the PluginConfig.cmake file that you can change to make it per-machine; that means you need admin rights to install it, but it should work for all users.

Comment: Hi taxilian, thanks for your reply. 

First my user account actually am the administrator, and the plugin is installed under "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\myplugin\". When running IE by just clicking, it is in non-admin mode which plugin works well, but if explicitly run it as admin, plugin fails to load.

Second, I also tried your suggestion that make the plugin per-machine, but it doesn't work either.

You can try firebreath example plugins that can also reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hi taxilian, it turns out you are right. Register plugin as per-machine will solve this problem. Previously, I don't see it works, because my nsis installer doesn't do the right job, which explicitly write the register to HKCU. Now I change it to HKLM, it works.

Answer (score 2):

We had an issue because IE9 uses a shadow file system if you write to disk in protected mode which led to issues. Changing from AppData/Roaming to AppData/LocalLow allowed us to write correctly and not have our plugin crash.

Not sure if this is the issue, but it took a while to figure out so posting it here. The UAC is the reason it can't write.